# How set something with mouselistener based on getX and getY to labels?

Tags: java, swing, label, mouselistener

I've got this: label = new JLabel[9][9]. I want to set a new icon to the label (for the label, where I clicked, of course). I've got a panel(with gridlayout) too, in which I have the labels, it's 500x500.

So in mouselistener, I know, I can use getX() and getY(). After that, how can I say in which row and column I clicked? Should I divide the panel to little areas? I hope the question was understandable. I read questions here, like this, but I do not really found answer...

Up to now I wrote this:

```
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                int mouseX = e.getX();
                int mouseY = e.getY();
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;



                URL url = Click.class.getResource("image.png");
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
                label[i][j] = new JLabel(img);
            }
```

Comment: *"I've got this: label.."* At this point I'd use an undecorated `JButton` or `JToggleButton` .. *"`URL url = Click.class.getResource("image.png");`"* .because buttons have inbuilt methods to change between images when hovered, focused, pressed etc. No need for any specific listener.

Comment: *"..how can I say in which row and column I clicked?"* If the listener has been added to every label, you can `e.getSource()` to know which one is the source of the event..

Comment: Thank you. And can you give me a little example for getSource(),so how can I use this ?

Comment: I agree with Andrew: don't try to determine which label the mouse _should_ be over by using the layout to calculate where the labels _should_ be but provide the listener to every component (i.e. label) and let the UI framework do the work for you.

Comment: The event source is the component you clicked on. Just check whether it is a label, cast and set the new icon on the source.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's working now.

Comment: @programme. `can you give me a little example for getSource(),so how can I use this ?` - did you search the forum (or the web) for example that use the getSource() method. Develop some basic problem solving skills so you don't have to keep asking questions like this. Learn how to use the resource of the internet. It is not just about asking questions but learning how to do your own research as well.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have got a panel with a GridLayout. You haven't said what you have named it, so let's call it `p`.

In your `mouseClicked` method, do:

```
JLabel jlb = (JLabel) p.getComponentAt(e.getX(),e.getY());
```

Now do whatever you want to do on it.